# Android custom Event to Javascript EventListener

Tags: javascript, android, events, dom-events, android-event

Is it possible to create in Android event, which sends data to Havascript EventListener in WebView?

For example:
In background, I start thread what search updates on server. When updates was found I send event to update data on user page. And I don't want reload view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the only way I found out was using JavaScript injection:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:helloWorld(\"hi\");"); //or postUrl if using HTTP POST
```

This will cause the function `helloWorld` defined in the JavaScript of the webpage to be called with parameter value `hi`.